# Maximum Number Of Points (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is like the following.

Let $n$ **blue** lines, no two of which are parallel and no three concurrent, be drawn on a plane.
An intersection of two **blue** lines is called a **blue** point.

Through any two **blue** points that have not already been joined by a **blue** line, a **red** line is drawn.

An intersection of two **red** lines is called a **red** point,
and an intersection of **red** line and a **blue** line is called a **purple** point.

What is the maximum possible number of **purple** points?

**P.S.**
This is from **Turkey National Olympiad Second Round 1994**.
I have no solution and can't come up with anything.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each pair of blue lines intersect in a blue point, so there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ blue points. Each blue point is connected to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - (2n-3)$ other blue points with red lines, so there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \left(\frac{\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - (2n-3)}{2}\right)$ red lines. Each red line intersects each blue line, but is concurrent with two blue lines at its two blue points, so each red line contributes $n-4$ purple points, plus the original $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ blue points, assuming $n > 3$.

The total number of purple points then becomes $\displaystyle \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - (2n-3)\right)(n-4) + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$